# Chrome extension to make page is reloading more visible

Tags: chrome

If you have a good number of tabs they will be narrow enough you can't see the page loading indicator in the tab and there's absolutely nothing in a browser page to indicate it is currently reloading. Is there something to make it better visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there's absolutely nothing in a browser page to indicate it is currently reloading

I usually have very narrow tabs.
The top left corner of my Chrome browser screen looks like this:

[image: Top left corner of Chrome browser screen.]

When I reload a page, the circular arrow symbol changes to an "X" until the reload has finished.
(If it is taking too long, clicking the "X" cancels the reload request.)

Comment: Ray means the circular arrow symbol next to the address bar. This might be self evident to those who reload the page by pressing that button but I always use the keyboard so I didn't even realize that button survived (most buttons from early browsers didn't).